# Parse/Parse.h file not found when Xcode Quits

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I added the Parse SDK in my project and everything was well. However when I quit Xcode and opened the project I got these errors:

```
Parse/Parse.h file not found
```

I deleted the Parse Framework and re-added it to my project and the errors went away. However whenever I quit Xcode and reopen this project I get these errors.

What do I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Its really use full answer :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/42486383/3752143

Its work for me.

Answer (score 8):

@Tuyen answer help me solve this problem. However I'd like to make it more clear.
In `Build Setting > Framework Search Path`, add a new path `$(PROJECT_DIR)` and set recursive.

I put all 3rd party framework under project directory /framework, so this setting will surely find the framework file.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Here is my solution.

1. Drag Parse.framework to a folder in xcode (check copy)
2. Change "Framework Search Path" in Build Settings to relative path. Ex: MyProject/Libraries
3. Optional for more clean code: in xcode, drag Parse.framework to folder Frameworks

After these steps, this problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

create new parse app
download parse sdk for ios

create new project - master detail
go to build settings
    under search paths >> framework search paths >>
        1) debug - add $(PROJECT_DIR)/**
        2) release - add $(PROJECT_DIR)/**

go to general tab
    under Linked frameworks and libraries, 
        Add the following frameworks from parse SDK
            Parse.framework
            ParseCrashReporting.framework
            Bolts.framework
            ParseUI.framework

```
        Also add the below frameworks
            AudioToolbox.framework
            SystemConfiguration.framework

        Add the below frameworks using "Add framewors popup" -->> Add other -->> ctrl+shift+g --> enter /usr/lib/ -->>
            choose the following
                1) libz.1.dylib
                2) libsqlite3.dylib
```

create new file -->> chose Objective-C type -->>create.
    Xcode will ask you whether you want to create a bridging header? select yes.
    it create 2 files. one is .m file and one is .h file
    go to .h file, add the following line
        #import

Open up the AppDelegate.swift file, uncomment and edit the setApplicationId line in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function with your keys:
Example:
Parse.setApplicationId("sJjEQei2m15RD9MJiZjVtygI1o6wQ23TxhdIllUo", 
  clientKey: "IZDfhmPiO2b01yEacRBAStyKAznXrguFku78pWO3")

Test the SDK

First make sure to include our SDK imports at the top of your ViewController.swift file:

import Parse

Then copy and paste this code into your app, for example in the viewDidLoad function of ViewController.swift:

```
let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
testObject["foo"] = "bar"
testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  print("Object has been saved.")
}
```

Run your app. A new object of class TestObject will be sent to the Parse Cloud and saved. When you're ready, click the button below to test if your data was sent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works. Never had this problem like you before. Anyway check [this](https://parse.com/questions/parseparseh-file-not-found) one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Still having the same problem :(