# Getting 'Parse/Parse.h' file not found' error ONLY when archiving iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

Whenever I try to run my iOS app, it runs just fine, however when I archive it in order to submit a build to the app store, it throw this error:

> 'Parse/Parse.h' file not found`

When looking at the frameworks installed, it shows that Parse.h is indeed in the project folder:

[image]

I've tried all the different solutions (removing the frameworks and re-adding, adding the the project directory to Framework Search Paths, etc) suggested in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764566/external-framework-file-file-h-parse-parse-h-file-not-found) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330128/parse-parse-h-file-not-found-after-update-with-cocoapods) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355593/parse-parse-h-file-not-found-when-xcode-quits) [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355569/parse-parse-h-file-not-found-xcode-6) about this, and none have worked.

It's been suggested that `Bolts.framework` and `Parse.framework` may have duplicate Parse.h files, but I can't seem to find any duplicates. Also mentioned was the possibility of it being caused by an outdated `Bolts.framework` version, but I added the latest version and no dice. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

try  https://parse.com/questions/parseparseh-file-not-found
Hey, I solved it! I moved the parse.framework folder into a sup folder /projectname/framework/parse.framework/

after I moved the parse.framework folder back into Project folder (/projectname/parse.framework) Xcode was able to import the parse/parse.h file! :) Maybe that helps to! :)